# how to merge all JSON_TYPE data type values in a mysql JSON column with a single mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Given I have a JSON column called arbitraryjsonvalues in a mysql database table and this column has the following values

```
arbitraryjsonvalues
===================
Dickers,
45,
true,
false,
null,
["a", "man", "book", "girl", "cat"],
["fish", "dog", "cat"],
{
   "foo": {
     "boo": [
       "babe1", "babe2", "babe3"
     ],
     "big": {
       "cat": 16,
       "dog": 90
     },
     "small": ["paradise", "hell"]
   },
   "goo": "heavens gate",
   "yeah": "rice pot on fire"
},
{
   "foo": {
     "lover": [
       "lover1", "lover2", "lover3"
     ],
     "big": {
       "cylinder": 16,
       "cone": 90
     },
     "small": ["banner", "logo"]
   },
   "yeah": "pizza on the table"
}
```

I am trying to form a query that will merge all of these JSON values into a single array and the result should be either of the following

```
 Result 1
 ==================
 [
   "a", 
   "man", 
   "book", 
   "girl", 
   "cat", 
   "fish", 
   "dog", 
   "Dickers", 
   45, 
   true, 
   false,
   {
     "foo": {
       "lover": [
         "lover1", "lover2", "lover3"
       ],
       "boo": [
         "babe1", "babe2", "babe3"
       ],
       "big": {
         "cylinder": 16,
         "cone": 90,
         "cat": 16,
         "dog": 90
       },
       "small": ["paradise", "hell", "banner", "logo"]
     },
     "goo": "heavens gate",
     "yeah": ["rice pot on fire", "pizza on the table"]
   }
 ]

 Result 2
 ==================
 [
   [],
   {
     "foo": {
       "lover": [],
       "boo": [],
       "big": {
         "cylinder": [],
         "cone": [],
         "cat": [],
         "dog": []
       },
       "small": []
     },
     "goo": [],
     "yeah": []
   }
 ]
```

I have this query that can merge all OBJECT values but with the presence of non OBJECT values, the query fails

```
select cast(
  concat('{'
    group_concat(
      substring(arbitraryjsonvalues, 2, length(arbitraryjsonvalues) - 2)
    ),
  '}')
as json) arbitraryjsonvaluesmerged
from ITEMS
where arbitraryjsonvalues != JSON_OBJECT();
```

In an attempt to have something close i formed this logic which might look erroneous, so I have been doing research on how to use mysql CASE with group_concat, and other stuffs to see where my query is not working or how to make it work but yet no solution...

I humbly wish to show my erroneous attempt with hope that someone can point me to the right direction.

```
select cast(
  concat('['
    (
      group_concat(
        CASE 
          WHEN JSON_TYPE(arbitraryjsonvalues) = "OBJECT" THEN 
            substring(
              arbitraryjsonvalues, 2, length(arbitraryjsonvalues) - 2
            )
          ELSE arbitraryjsonvalues
        END
      )
    ),
  ']')
as json) arbitraryjsonvaluesmerged
from ITEMS
where arbitraryjsonvalues != JSON_OBJECT() AND arbitraryjsonvalues != JSON_ARRAY() AND arbitraryjsonvalues != '' 
AND arbitraryjsonvalues != NULL;
```

I am currently trying to merge only the OBJECT type with the following query below but having the following error

```
Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_merge_preserve: "Invalid value." at position 0.

set @t = @@group_concat_max_len;
set @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;
SELECT (
  select coalesce(
    json_merge_preserve(
      '{}', 
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
          "'",
          (
            CASE
              WHEN JSON_TYPE(arbitraryjsonvalues) = "OBJECT"
              THEN arbitraryjsonvalues
            END
          ),
          "'"
        )
      )
    ),
    JSON_OBJECT()
  ) FROM ITEMS
);
set @@group_concat_max_len = @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you stumble into this question, there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725045/how-to-merge-all-mysql-json-column-values-with-json-merge-patch) on stackoverflow